# does diluting sea water from iceberg melt raise levels

Tags: climate-science

I'm asking this because I just joined and am not permitted to comment on the question "Does the sea level increase if an iceberg melts?"

According google search, one liter of sea water contains 35 grams of sea salt with a density of 1027 grams/liter. So, if 35 grams of sea salt are removed from 1 liter of sea water, the water now weighs 992 grams and assuming for this argument, it is fresh water with a volume of about 0.992 liter. If an additional 1 liter of fresh water is added to this plus the 35 grams of sea salt, the resulting solution weighs 2027 grams. According to density calculator http://www.csgnetwork.com/h2odenscalc.html, this solution (more than 17000 mg/L salinity) has a volume of about 1.999... liters. One liter a sea water and one liter of fresh water is less than two liters when combined. Is this wrong?

I used 4 degrees Celsius for this calculation.

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Similar effect with [liquour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alcohol_by_volume#Volume_change).

Comment: see similar question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/345381/does-the-sea-level-increase-if-an-iceberg-melts and note the "very very slightly" in the chosen answer melting ice floating in the sea will not significantly change any level, because of Archimedew principle. It is icebergs on land that will if melted and run down to the sea that will do so..

Comment: Weather is removing water from the ocean, precipitating on land and returning to the ocean. Some of this freezes. When in the history of the planet were there more, less or no icebergs at all in the ocean?

Comment: Understand that no "experts" are claiming that melting icebergs (defined as a floating chunk of ice) will raise sea levels.  It's the ice on land (ie, glaciers) which are the (major) concern, as global temperatures rise.

Comment: The answer is "yes" but the effect is small.

Answer (score 0):

This effect is known as [cabbeling](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cabbeling).