# How does the melting ice cube in a glass of water doesn't change the water volume?

Tags: volume, ice

that's problably a very noob question, and answer that i found is: the water volume was always the same, what is kinda obivius, but doesn't seen enought to me. So I can't stop thinking, were did the extra ice volume above the water line goes, I had a tought, and a wanna know if it makes any sense.

Is that volume above the water line, exactly the air volume inside the whole ice cube that will be lose during the melting?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does ice melting not change the water level in a container?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/110645/)

Comment: Thanks man i will dive into that

Answer (score 0):

When water freezes, it expands. The part of the ice above the waterline is the amount the volume increased when it froze. The water's weight does not change from liquid to ice state. Therefore the ice displaces the same weight of water when it is frozen as when it is a liquid, so the level does not change.

Comment: An ice cube displaces its weight in water, but not its volume.

Comment: @DavidWhite Exactly, I will edit "amount" to "weight" to be more clear. Thanks.